# How to add a cache programmatically in WildFly/JBoss using the Detyped Java API

Tags: configuration, jboss, client, wildfly, infinispan

There are many examples available how to add a **datasource** programatically using the *Native Management API* https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Management%20API%20reference.html and its Java implementation in the **JBoss DMR** *(Dynamic Model Representation)* https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-dmr

A tutorial using the Java library with a datasource addition as an example is given at *MasterTheBoss* for instance:
https://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-as-7/using-jboss-management-api-programmatically/

Thus, I could not find helpful documentation or an example where a more complex strucure with sub-elements was added to the configuration. For the datasource, all (XML-)elements under datasource are to be addressed as properties of the datasource and then rendered by the server itself, whereas for the following case of an **Infinispan** cache, I could not find the matching approach for adding the configuration through *JBoss DMR*.
The following snippet from the XML representation of the configuration needs to be added in the **infinispan subsystem** using the API:

```
<cache-container name="cache1">
    <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
    <replicated-cache name="replicated1">
        <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
    </replicated-cache>
    <replicated-cache name="replicated2">
        <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
    </replicated-cache>
</cache-container>
```

A helpful hint would be great

Answer (score 2):

jboss-cli can show you the dmr structure of your command using the echo-dmr command:

```
echo-dmr /core-service=module-loading:read-attribute(name=module-roots, include-defaults)
{
    "address" => [("core-service" => "module-loading")],
    "operation" => "read-attribute",
    "include-defaults" => true,
    "name" => "module-roots"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint - it did not exactly lead to the solution, but it helped on the way to it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Got it finally. A good approach seems to be as follows:

1. Search the **API documentation** for the aspects you want to address, e.g. the transport configuration for caches https://docs.wildfly.org/26.1/wildscribe/subsystem/infinispan/cache-container/transport/jgroups/index.html which pointed out that the jgroups type needs to be used here
2. Use the **jboss-cli** to test what you constructed (helpful might be this overview for examples of the standard configuration: https://gist.github.com/cheinema/a68ae81f1bbdc695c755)
3. When you found the right command(s), make **translate** them **to** the **Java DMR API**
   The following example shows how this could look like:

*/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=cache1/transport=jgroups:add(lock-timeout=20)*

Which can be used in Java like this:

```
ModelNode cacheContainer = new ModelNode();

cacheContainer.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("subsystem","infinispan");
    
cacheContainer.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("cache-container","cache1");        
cacheContainer.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("transport","jgroups");     
    
cacheContainer.get("lock-timeout").set(20);     
cacheContainer.get(ClientConstants.OP).set(ClientConstants.ADD);
```

You first **add** to the address you want to modify in the first lines, then **define** the **attribute** you want to **set** there (lock-timeout in this case), followed by the **operation** - here **ADD** (may also be REMOVE for example).